# Looking into Smarta

Tags: advaita, smarta

Can someone please refer to a scripture which describes the Smarta god and the 5 main forms. Also a scripture which adds Skanda as a form.

Clarification: I mean Nirguna Brahman and learning about the metaphysics of Ishvara, but I want advaitic secular sources and not puranas which can be attributed a variety of ways. Think of works like Yatindramatadipika a Vishistadvaitic work, but for Advaitans and Nirguna brahman primarily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the maṅgalācaraṇa of [Tattvabindu](https://archive.org/details/tattvabinduvachaspatimisratattvavibhavanaparamesvaraed.ramaswamisastriv.a.1991_202003_31_G/page/n225/mode/2up?view=theater), Vācaspati Miśra offers namaskāra to the pañcadevatās -

> ahaye budhnyāya namo bradhnyāya namo namo'stu gaṇapataye / 
> āryāyai bhāratyai namo namo viṣṭaraśravase //

*ahaye budhnyāya* refers to Śiva, *bradhnyāya* refers to Sūrya, *gaṇapataye* refers to Gaṇapati, *āryāyai bhāratyai* refers to Devī,  *viṣṭaraśravase* refers to Viṣṇu. Here all the pañcadevatās are namaskṛta in the following order - Śiva, Sūrya, Gaṇapati, Devī, & Viṣṇu.

In [Bhāmati's maṅgalācaraṇa](https://archive.org/details/BrahmaSutraShankaraBhashyaBhamatiVachaspatiBhamatiHindiVyakhyaSwamiYogindranandPart1Chowkambha_201806/page/n19/mode/2up?view=theater) on Śāṅkarabhāṣya (on Brahmasūtras), Vācaspati Miśra offers namaskāra to four of the ṣaṇmata devatās (including Skanda) -

> mārtaṇḍatilakasvāmimahāgaṇapatīn batam / 
> viśvavandyān namasyāmaḥ sarvasiddhividhāyinaḥ // 
> brahmasūtrakṛte tasmai vedavyāsāyāvedhase /  
> jñānaśaktyavatārāya namo bhagavato hareḥ //

Mārtaṇḍa (Sūrya), Tilakasvāmin (Skanda), Gaṇapati and Kṛṣṇa Dvaipāyana Vyāsa (author of Brahmasūtras) as an avatāra of jñāna śakti of Hari (Viṣṇu), are namaskṛta here together.

Even though Ṛṣi Veda Vyāsa is an avatāra of Hari (also stated in the ślokas), still he is of manuṣya yoni and is namaskṛta primarily because he is author of the Brahmasūtras (to which Vācaspati was writing a subcommentary), and so if one doesn't take him as part of the namaskāra to devatās, then only three of ṣaṇmata (Sūrya, Skanda, Gaṇeśa) are namaskṛta here.

Comment: Very good, but is their one invocation which includes all 6 of them. The latter one is more indirect.

Comment: It's direct, because it's a part of maṅgalācaraṇa at the start of the commentary. *Usually*, six together aren't namaskṛta afaik in any śāstra. @Haridasa

Comment: Well, your answer sure does answer and a very good answer as well as a further continuation is there any primarily devotional text with all these characters being equally praised?

Comment: within a single śāstra, it would be rare to find all six being praised. I am not yet aware. @Haridasa

Comment: I respect that and thank you for your answer the effort is what matters and I understand an answerer cannot be 100% perfect to the questioner's demands. I just posted another question regarding Varna if you have time, please answer as it is of more urgent importance, other than that have a great rest of your day :)

Comment: Btw Bingming what is this Bhamati I am curious in it's regards infact the whole shastra or scholarly work what is it about?

Comment: It's a commentary on Śaṅkara's bhāṣya on Brahmasūtras. @Haridasa Brahmasūtras is one of the prasthānatrayī, which are three core canonical śāstras of Vedānta.

Comment: Interestingly it seems to only have roughly 700 pages is this pdf only volume one? https://ignca.gov.in/Asi_data/778.pdf Is this an independent work of commentary or...

Comment: The one linked in the answer is only the first volume. @Haridasa

Comment: That one I cannot access likely due to being on school Chromebook.

Comment: @Haridasa The link that u shared is of Bhamati:Catuh Sutri. The first 4 Sutra from the first 4 adhikaranams together they are called Catuh Sutri.  So it is a commentary on those Sankara Bhasya. It's not an independent work its a part of Bhamati

Answer (score 2):

Since you are not looking for Purana references, but you are looking for references from advaitic sources, [here is one reference](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?scms=1&choose=1&&language=ro&field_chapter_value=15&field_nsutra_value=20) from Gudarthadipika (Gita bhAshya) of Sri Madhusudhana Saraswati that mentions the 5 forms.

> **śaivāḥ saurāśca gāṇēśā vaiṣṇavāḥ śaktipūjakāḥ.** bhavanti yanmayāḥ sarvē sōhamasmi paraḥ śivaḥ৷৷

> I am that Supreme Auspicious One (Siva) in whom get identified all the followers of Shiva, Surya, Ganesha, Vishnu and worshippers of Shakti.